# How can I replicate the AlertDialog using Activity as a dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I've an `AlertDialog` that is used throughout my app. I am happy with how this looks and what to replicate this to look the exact same as when I use an `Activity as a Dialog`. I need to use the `Activity as a Dialog` instead of the `AlertDialog` in some instances as I have to prevent the app starting a new activity which only happens in certain situations.

Here is how my `AlertDialog` looks.

[image: AlertDialog]

Here is my `Activity As A Dialog`

[image]

How can I match the second dialog to look exactly as the Alert Dialog? The primary dialog uses my default theme with the pink radio buttons but the second one doesn't. Also the second dialog is wider and shorter. Is there any way I can find the layout properties for the alert dialog and just add these properties to the xml for the `AAAD`? Or is there a better way to go about it?

Here is the builder code for the `Alert Dialog`

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alt_bld.setTitle("Alert Dialog"); 


    alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(myArray.toArray(new String[myArray.size()]), 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

Code for `AAAD`

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_da_aamount_to_finish);
    setTitle("Activity As A Dialog");
```

Manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".DaAAmountToFinish"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.MinWidth">
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"></activity>
```

The xml for this activity is just a RadioGroup with three buttons.

How should I go about this?

If I change the manifest theme for `AAAD` to `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">` It appears in the style I want but as a whole activity. How do i keep the dialog look and implement this theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate the structure of the dialog, you could use the Layout inspector tool of Android Studio, it will display the view tree.
[Layout inspector guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)

For the pink color, Android fetch it from your style file. This color should be the colorAccent or colorPrimary property of your AppTheme (can't remember exactly).

```
<style name="AppTheme.Normal.Watermelon" parent="Base.AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/watermelon</item>
    <!-- or -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/watermelon</item>
</style>
```

Hope this is somewhat helpful !

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get somewhere with this.